# How can I determine number of jobs for a given technology from a list I have obtained in .json format from GitHub job opening API in python?

Tags: python, api, github, pagination

My task is to Write a function to get the number of jobs for the given technology.
Note: The API gives a maximum of 50 jobs per page.
If you get 50 jobs per page, it means there could be some more job listings available.
So if you get 50 jobs per page you should make another API call for next page to check for more jobs.
If you get less than 50 jobs per page, you can take it as the final count.

Following is my code

```
baseurl = "https://jobs.github.com/positions.json"
def get_number_of_jobs(technology):
    number_of_jobs = 0
    tech = technology
    page= 0
    PARAMS  = {'technology':tech , 'page': page}
    jobs=requests.get(url=baseurl,params = PARAMS )
    if jobs.ok:             
        listings = jobs.json()
    number_of_jobs=len(listings)
    if number_of_jobs==50:
        page= page+1 
        PARAMS  = {'technology':tech , 'page': page}
        jobs=requests.get(url=baseurl,params = PARAMS )
        if jobs.ok:             
            listings2 = jobs.json()
    number_of_jobs= number_of_jobs + len(listings2)
    return technology,number_of_jobs
```

Now I can not figure out how to do the pagination in this function? Meaning how to check if there are more than 50 job posting for a specific technology or not and if it is then run the code again and get those postings as well?

I print the output as

```
print(get_number_of_jobs('python'))

('python', 100)
```

Can someone please help?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you write 2 get requests? You should write a function for it

Comment: Can you please give me full code.

Comment: Check out ``while`` loops and increment ``page`` accordingly.

Comment: @Suman I have edited the code again,  that's my full code

Comment: @noora please put base url

Comment: @Suman baseurl = "https://jobs.github.com/positions.json"

Comment: @MikeScotty how do I specify a while loop to stop looping if its getting the same postings again and again, because while loop will keep running till it meets the condition no_of_jobs ==50 , it does not know to stop  if its getting the same data again

Comment: That's why you should increment ``page``. At some point you will get less than 50 jobs, that's when the while loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

**Please let me know if should work**

```
import requests
baseurl = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json'

total_job = 0

def get_number_of_jobs(technology, page):
    global total_job
    PARAMS  = {'technology':technology , 'page': page}
    jobs=requests.get(url=baseurl,params = PARAMS )
    total_job += len(jobs.json()) if jobs.ok else 0
    return len(jobs.json()) if jobs.ok else 0

def get_jobs(technology):
    page = 0
    while get_number_of_jobs(technology, page) >= 50:page+=1
    return total_job       


print(get_jobs('python'))
```

Comment: I have to do both jobs in one function

Comment: @noora just use while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
baseurl = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json'    
def get_number_of_jobs(technology):
    number_of_jobs = 0
    page = 0
    while True:
      payload = {"description":technology,"page":page}
      r = requests.get(baseurl,params=payload)
      if r.ok:
        data = r.json()
      number_of_jobs = len(data)
      if number_of_jobs >= 50:
        page += 1
        continue
      else:
        break    
    return technology,number_of_jobs
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.